# how do i find node and its child nodes using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, nodes

Please let me know the code syntax how to use Node.childNodes from the documentation
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#module-xml.dom
I am beginner to python and selenium. I have tried using:

```
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_id("pie4")
x = elem.childNodes
print x
```

I have also tried:

```
self.dom.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].firstChild.data
```

But both fail.

Answer (score 2):

`elem` is [`WebElement`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#30). You could use `elem.find_elements_by_xpath()` to select relevant child elements e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from contextlib import closing

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome as Browser # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

with closing(Browser()) as browser:
    browser.get('http://stackoverflow.com/q/9548523')
    elem = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(
        lambda br: br.find_element_by_class_name('related'))
    children = elem.find_elements_by_xpath('./*')
    for child in children:
        print("<%s> %r" % (child.tag_name, child.text[:60]))
```

#### Output

```
<div> u'How to handle dialog box through selenium with python?'
<div> u'Networkx node traversal'
<div> u'How to set up Selenium to work with Visual Studio .NET using'
<div> u'How can I find text location with Selenium?'
<div> u"Using Selenium's Python API - How do I get the number of row"
<div> u'Selenium in Python'
...[snip]...
```

Comment: code looks like this :
<div id="pie4" class="left-top sap-workareaitem-content sap-chart" data-color="blue" data-charttype="pie" data-dimension="CATEGORY" data-title="CATEGORY-PIE" data-sap-widget="chart" style="display: block;">
<svg class="sap-piechart" width="105" height="105">
<g>
<path style="pointer-events: all;" transform="translate(53,53)" fill="rgb(120,160,200)" title="Others : 13" d="M3.053962955373712e-15,-49.875A49.875,49.875 0 0,1 48.393499348015325,12.065854543033433L25.470262814744906,6.350449759491281A26.25,26.25 0 0,0 1.607348923880901e-15,-26.25Z">

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion as above .I tried ,for loop, for the id as find_element_by_id("pie4"), i get an error webelement is not iterable .

Comment: @user1117498: you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9548523/edit) your question and include there properly formatted xml