# How to access grand childs of a node using XPath in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am preparing a web-scraping script which supposed to find list of attorneys in an area through a business directory web-site. I use chrome driver to fill out search keywords and the area values.

Since some of the hits don't have phone number, I would like to iterate through list of DIVs corresponding to search results and then check if the it has the phone number as a grand grand child and if yes then I get the phone number too otherwise I leave that field blank.

I have come up with two ways to do it as per below code.

```
import time
import json as js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Divorce+Attorneys&geo_location_terms=sun+diego'
RsultsList = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
ThereIsNext = True
while ThereIsNext:
    
    # find ads.
    nAddResults = len( driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='result flash-ad']"))

    #print 'add size = %d' % nAddResults
    for i in range(nAddResults):
        phone1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='result flash-ad']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]")[i].text
        BusinessName1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='result flash-ad']//a[@class='business-name']")[i].text

        elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='result flash-ad']")
        phone2 = elem.find_element_by_xpath("/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]")[i].text
        BusinessName2 = elem.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='business-name']")
```

The first one is prone to error as records with no phone no. do NOT necessary show up at the end. So I come up with the second way. However, I get the below error message if try the second.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PythonApplication3\
PythonApplication3\AtorneyList.py", line 23, in <module>
    phone2 = elem.find_element_by_xpath("/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1
]").text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please let me know what I am missing. I have checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548523/how-do-i-find-node-and-its-child-nodes-using-selenium-with-python?s=1%7C1.1269) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548523/how-do-i-find-node-and-its-child-nodes-using-selenium-with-python/9548919?s=2%7C0.1580#9548919) already and couldn't understand.

Much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Your xpaths look very brittle, are there no classes or ids you can use to locate the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `find_elements()` returns either list of [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) or empty list. You're storing this result into a list variable name `elem`.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

This occurs because you're going to find nested [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) on `elem` list that's why **you're calling as `elem.find_element_by_xpath()` which is absolutely wrong.**

Actually [`find_element()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) or [`find_elements`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements) is used to search the element on the **page context** or the **context of the [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)** instead of `list`.

So you should try to find list of [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) from `driver` means page context and then iterate to find further nested [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) using this element context as below :-

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='result flash-ad']")

for elem in elems:
    phone2 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]").text
    BusinessName2 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='business-name']").text
```